# How can I convert an exterior light junction box to an exterior duplex outlet?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have two dedicated circuits that were supposed to be set up with exterior outlets, high up on the wall to run Christmas lights.  What I got was two circuits terminated with wire nuts in junction boxes with plastic covers.

If I try to install exterior outlets they of course would NOT hang in the traditional vertical position.

Is there any way to convert these boxes short of cutting them out of the stucco and installing the correct boxes?

Comment: I want to know just how many amps you think your Christmas lights are going to need! ;)

Comment: In seriousness though - could you post a picture of the outlet in question?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Plastic Raised Switch Box Cover]

Do you have room to install a "raised switch box cover"?  I put that in quotes since I don't know what it is called but I found a picture of what I meant (and that is what they call it).  I think it would let you use two receptacles but it would stick out a little further and you may have to find a waterproof version if this is for outside.

Answer (score 1):

The orientation of the plugs is not that important, as waterproof covers come in both vert and horizontal styles. I hope they are GFI protected!!!   I really would like to see a pic of what we have to start with, so I can tell better what needs to be done. Is the junction box an exterior type? Does it have screw mounting centers for a weatherproof recpt cover?